# Can't connect to MySQL server on 'public_ip_address' (110)

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, database-connection, mysql-workbench, remote-access

I'm trying to connect to my local mysql database from my EC2 instance. unfortunately I wasn't able to.

This was the cmd I run from my EC2 to connect to my local Mysql database.

I was able to get my Public IP address using https://whatismyipaddress.com/
then I create a user using a user with the following cmd

```
mysql --host=public_ip_address --port=3306 --user=mongotop --password
```

These are the steps  I followed to create the user and grant privileges.

```
CREATE USER 'mongotop'@'public_ip_address' IDENTIFIED BY 'user_password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON instagram.*  TO 'mongotop'@'public_ip_address' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

then I create a configuration file `~/.my.cnf` and this was the file content.

```
[mysqld]
user        = mysql
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
bind-address        =  0.0.0.0
key_buffer      = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
log_error                = /var/log/mysql/error.log
max_binlog_size         = 100M

[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[mysql]

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M
```

I also did go ahead and turned my Mac machine firewall off.

Did I miss any step or does the configuration file in the not in the proper location or the appropriate configuration settings.

Comment: Is your router forwarding traffic on port 3306 to your Mac local IP address?

Comment: No. should I do that in my SSH cmd when I connect to EC2 like the following?  `ssh -L 3310:public_ip_address:3306 -i '~/.ssh/aws-key.pem' ec2-user@ec2-ip-address.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com`

Comment: Well if you are not forwarding traffic to your Mac, I don't think you'll be able to connect from outside your local network

Comment: I can't imagine why you want to do this. For production you should use an Amazon managed database or install mySQL on your EC2 instance. For development, install local copies of whatever you're running on your EC2 system.